# How to retrieve all viewstate lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I'm saving Viewstates like this with several students:

```
 ViewState[currentStudent] = currentGradesList;
```

But now i need to take all the viewstates to get the average of all grades, i've learnt to do it with strings like so:

`foreach (string str in ViewState.Keys) {....}` and that works.

But now when i try

```
foreach(List<double> grades in ViewState.Keys) {....}
```

the "grades" remain null and i get the error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double]'.
```

I guess it says that Keys are strings, but how would i then get all the lists??

Comment: You should not use ViewState for these purposes, how do these values come to ViewState? Can you get them from any source, like DB/file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping through the names of the keys in your `foreach` loop, not the actual values.  You use the value of the foreach loop variable (which is now the name of a key in your ViewState dictionary) to go get the value from the viewstate.

Change your foreach loop to something like this

```
foreach(var key in ViewState.keys)[
    var grades = ViewState[key] as List<double>;
    //LINQ has built in Average and Sum abilities on lists
    //I don't know what a CurrentStudentGrades looks like
    //but here is an example of using the built in average
    var studentAverage = grades.Average(x=>x.Grade);
    //do whatever else you are wanting to do
}
```

Comment: Thank you friend, you are right i mixed name and value.

I've never used var or as, so i did it like this instead :)
foreach (string str in ViewState.Keys)
                {
                    List<double> templist = (List<double>)ViewState[str];
                }
Now im just waiting for SOF to allow me to accept answer, you're too fast! :D

Comment: a linq solution is good and simple, but i am preparing for the exam and they want me not to use it

Comment: @humudu - awesome buddy, glad you got it working again.  I understand on the LINQ, its good to know how to do it yourself.  Oh, and var is just telling the compiler to 'implicitly' determine the type.  It will look at a var declaration and say, hey, you assigned me a string as a value, I must be a string variable!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (string str in ViewState.Keys)
{
    var grades = ViewState[str] as List<double>;
    if(grades != null)
    {
         var average = grades.Average();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Nice and fast answer

Comment: Please explain your answers so that others in the future know why this works.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
I was looping through the names of the viewstate keys, not the values. So now i changed it to

```
Foreach (string str in ViewState.Keys) 
{ //And then the value of "str"...
 List<double> templist = (List<double>)ViewState[str];
```

And then the rest of my code which doesn't matter really but here it is to get average grade of each student, and all students together

```
foreach (double grade in templist)
{
currenttotal += grade;
}
currentaverage = currenttotal / templist.count;
AllAveragesList.add(currentaverage)

foreach (double average in AllAveragesList)
{
totalOfAll += average
}
averageOfAll = totalOfAll / AllAveragesList.count();`
```